# Override method body using Moq in .NET

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, moq, xunit

I have a web api controller with some GET function which I want to test. Inside of this GET function there is a public void method **SendCachingHeaders**:

```
public void SendCachingHeaders(int cacheFor) {
            Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age="+cacheFor+", public");
        }
```

In the test class I create **mockController**:

```
var mockController = new Mock<IRawEntityController>();
```

**SendCachingHeaders** is inside a controller which implements -> **IRawEntityController**

So I wanted to override **SendCachingHeaders** method body with *moq* object like this:

```
mockController.Setup(
                x => x.SendCachingHeaders(It.IsAny<int>())).
                Callback(() =>
                {
                    int i; //just to do something irrelevant
                });
```

When I run test however, I can see in debbuger, that original **SendCachingHeaders** method is called and my mocked object is totally ignored.

Did I totally wrong understand what **Callback** does, or I am missing something obvious?

*One more thing -> when I run test, a value of **cacheFor** (argument of **SendCachingHeaders** method is '5'. Probably irrelevant info.*

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you testing, when you mock the controller?!? Are you trying to test... the framework? This is obviously wrong, as the framework is tested by ASP.NET Core team. Second: You can't mock non-virtual, non-abstract and  non-interface methods (read: mocked method must be an interface, virtual (non-sealed) method/property or abstract (non-sealed) method/property

Comment: I am trying to test method from my controller. I was simply following this article: https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvc/controllers/testing.html ||| The only difference is I have void method inside my tested method. About the second point -> yeah, I have SendCachingHeaders in the interface, ofcourse.

Comment: Heh...?! How are you going to test your controller, when you mock `IRawEntityController`? Also you shouldn't mock the class you test, you mock it's dependencies. You'll need to show more code examples, but to me sounds like you did not use clean code and SOLID principles in your code, making it untestable

Comment: Hmm, probably you are right, it is not my code, I am just writing test for this. In addition, I am new at mocking & testing. I did mock dependencies, ofc. But anyway, the general problem is, how to override method body, or force the method to do nothing, when called from tested method?:)

Comment: If the method is not virtual, and not abstract and not an interface, you **can not mock it**. Mocking only works, on virtual, abstract or interfaces and only if they are not **sealed**. You would need to provide more code, if the class to be tested, the controller and the unit test method and its setup. Most likely you need to refactor the code to make it testable, hence why clean code and SOLID principles are important to produce testable code. Unlike Java, C# method and properties are **not virtual** by default

Comment: This is not a problem, method is declared in the interface. Also, I have tried marking it as virtual, it didn't change anything:(

Comment: But when you mock the interface, you can't test the implementation. Show the complete code. When you "unit test" against the mock, you will always get only what the mock is configured, but never testing the concrete implementation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189895/discussion-between-lucas-and-tseng).